# How do I make an Express routing wildcard not catch 404'd static files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm dealing with a recurring problem in my Express app right now, which is that if a static file is requested which doesn't exist, my app will return my default index as that file.

The short version of my routing in app.js is such:

```
const index = require('./routes/index');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/*', index);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("DIDN'T FIND A FILE");
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

The problem is that I never get the error or the print, because the wildcard will always serve my index router.

The server reports 200 for the request, and on the client I get the missing file whose contents is index.

I want the wildcard so that I can redirect bad urls to the main page. Is the only solution here to just run regex on the request and guess if it's supposed to be a file and then manually return a 404?

Comment: It's not at all clear how this should work. If you have one file in your static directory, say `about` and I request `/about2`, is that a 404 or a route your wildcard handles? How could you know? You can short circuit errors using the `fallthrough` option, but that will essentially remove your wildcard.

Comment: I guess coming from non-web programming, I see the idea of a file request as separate from a path request. I understand returning a file for a path request, but in my mind, I'd like a file request to work differently (for my own sanity and error checking during dev if nothing else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see this working is if you give express someway of knowing which urls are supposed to be static files and which should be handled by your wildcard.

For example, given the path: `/not_a_file`, the static middleware will look in the public folder and not find it. So is that a `404` or something handled by the wildcard?

This may not be what you're hoping for, but one way around this is to put all static files on a particular path and use the `fallthrough` option. For example if you set up static like this:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {fallthrough:false}));
```

Now requests for `/static/index` will serve the index if it's there and `/static/not_here` will fall through to  your error. Requests to all other paths will be picked up by your wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

So, the simplest way to fix this is to stop using the wildcard path that serves your index file.

Change this:

```
app.use('/*', index);
```

to this:

```
app.get('/', index);
```

Then, only a `/` path will call your index route handler.  Urls that didn't match a static file and weren't `/` will then hit your 404 handler.

If there are other reasons for the wildcard (I can't personally think of any), then you'd have to change the way you specify the `express.static()` handler.  Your `express.static()` line of code tells Express to look for all possible files to see if there's a match.  If not, then just keep going to other routes to see if a match is found there.  Because your static files have no required path prefix specified, there is no way to know which url is supposed to match a static route and which is not. Thus, the problem you have.

One way to fix that would be to do this:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {fallthrough: false}));
```

Then, you'd have to add `/public` to the start of every static URL.  Then, if a `/public/something` url request does not match in the static directory, the client will get a 404 and there will be no further routing to your wildcard.  The idea here is that you're giving Express some idea for which URLs should be handled by the `express.static()` handler and which ones shouldn't.  Only then, can it know whether to 404 one that it doesn't find or continue routing it to other route handlers.